# Helm - only create if nested values are set

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to exclude any yaml keys which do not have a value set.
My current approach is to wrap each key in an if statement...

```
container:
  spec:
   {{- if values.spec.x }}
    x: {{ values.spec.x }}
   {{- end}}
   {{- if values.spec.y }}
    y: {{ values.spec.y }}
   {{- end}}
   {{- if values.spec.z }}
    z: {{ values.spec.z }}
   {{- end}}
```

e.g.

```
for each child of container.spec:
  if the value != null:
    include as child of spec
  else:
    exclude from spec
```

I thought about wrapping the above in a _helper.tpl function to try to keep the main template tidy, but it would still include writing multiple if statements.

Is there a better way of doing the above?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly translate that pseudocode into Helm chart logic.  The trick is that a Go template `range` loop is basically equivalent to a "for" loop in most languages.  So:

```yaml
container:
  spec:
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.spec }}
{{- if ne $value nil }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

If you can just omit the unused keys from the values, then this becomes simpler and safer.  Helm includes a lightly-documented `toYaml` function that will render an arbitrary structure as YAML, but you can't really do any filtering or other preprocessing before writing it out.

```yaml
container:
  spec:
{{ .Values.spec | toYaml | indent 4 }}
```